# What is purpose of using static_cast<void>()?

Tags: c++, casting, void, static-cast

`static_cast<void>()` is the 'C++ way' of writing `void` conversion

In the en.cppreference.com website mentioned as discards the value of the expression. In below link four points on **Explanation** section

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast

Where and Why should we use `static_cast<void>()`? give a example..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a way to tell that it is ok for a variable to be unused suppressing corresponding compiler warning. This approach has been deprecated with introduction of `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute in C++17.

Comment: @TheVee No, it is ok for variable to be used: from **[dcl.attr.unused]** *3 [Note: For an entity marked maybe_unused, implementations should not emit a warning that the entity is  unused, or that the entity is used despite the presence of the attribute. —end note ]*

Comment: Unfortunately, the cast to void is still necessary for statements, to suppress warnings about unused expression results.

Answer (score 4):

The usual purpose of casting to `void` is to “use” the result of a computation.  In relatively strict build environments it is common to output warnings, or even errors, when a variable is declared, maybe even written to, but the result is never used.  If, in your code, you know you do not need a result somewhere, you can use the `static_cast<void>` method to mark the result as discarded – but the compiler will consider the variable used then and no longer create a warning or error.

An example:

```
#include <iostream>

int myFunction() __attribute__ ((warn_unused_result));
int myFunction()
{
  return 42;
}

int main()
{
  // warning: ignoring return value of 'int myFunction()',
  // declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  myFunction();

  // warning: unused variable 'result' [-Wunused-variable]
  auto result = myFunction();

  // no warning
  auto result2 = myFunction();
  static_cast<void>(result2);
}
```

When compiled with `g++ -std=c++14 -Wall example.cpp`, the first two function calls will create warnings.

As VTT pointed out in his post, from C++17 you have the option of using the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute instead.